# I have CustomerSession table in sql. Need to do flagging based on some scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have CustomerSession table in sql.
I want to do flagging for those user who have visited page 4 as 1 and rest as 0.

[image]

result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: mysql or sql server? Those are very different RDBMS products and you have both tagged. The solution here is likely to be different depending on product and version (window functions vs subquery). Also, please share sample data as text so we can replicate locally to help out.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: @CMGeek As I understand it, they want a column generated `flag_4` that is set to `1` for a user if any record for that user has the condition `page = '4'`.

Comment: @JNevill, isn't that what "flag_4" is?

Comment: @CMGeek Those are the desired results. Sample data is in the first screenshot. Innaya, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JNevill, do they want a table structure? A query?

Comment: @JNevill yes you are correct, sample data is the first SS, flag_4 is the extra column which we require for those users who visited page 4 in a particular session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with a simple `exists` check

```
select *, 
    case when exists (
        select * from CustomerSession t2 
        where t.user=t2.user and t2.page=4
    ) then 1 else 0 end flag_4
from CustomerSession t
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

@Innaya, I'm a bit confused as to your question, but I'll give it a shot... If what you are looking for is a query...

```
SELECT Session, [User], Page, flag_4 = CASE
   WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CustomerSession cs2 WHERE cs2.[User] = cs1.[User] and Page = '4') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM CustomerSession cs1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb6e2e3d15594e4a18c059a7fda6e423)